# Why doesn't transform-style: preserve-3d work?

Tags: html, css, transform

As far as I understand, `transform-style: preserve-3d;` property applies to the element and allows one to be positioned in a three-dimensional space. But I don't see any difference with and without `transform-style: preserve-3d;` property.

So, I have two examples.

1. With using `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

```css
.parent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.child:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

2. Without using `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

```css
.parent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.child:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So, what's the difference? As for me, these two examples look the same. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Preserve-3d' would make an impact on your example if you were to have elements that are overlapping.
Because none of your squares are actually sitting on top of each other, but rather are split-apart - you don't see any difference.

[Check this article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/) It has a very self-explanatory example in the very beginning, images included so you will see and understand the difference.